# Business rule separation based on AOP

Tags: domain-driven-design, aop

Doing Research on AOP.
AOP is for cross-cutting concerns. Found separation of business rules also considers as a cross-cutting concern.

Frameworks like RulesEngine, NRules use for business rules validation.
Then why someone will use AOP for a business rule separation?

After reading this 
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2405882315000071
Looking for How to find core concern, cross-cutting, rule concern(SRA & PRA).

Can someone help me with a study and example of AOP for business rule separation?
Also finding separation of the business rule using AOP with DDD.

Answer (score 0):

That is how you decompose your system and what are the boundaries. Check out volatility based decomposition of Jowal Lowy. There is a service called Engine. Its totally another thinking of building software and defining service boundaries.

Comment: Hi DmitriBodiu, I read about Volatility based decomposition by Juwal Lowy, look for a sample for better understanding but didn't get any.

Comment: Have a look at his new book "Righting software". He shows a concrete example how to decompose a system based on Volatility, not functional. The example in his book is a forex/options/commodities trading platform.

Comment: Also have a look at articles of this guy: http://www.waynecliffordbarker.co.za/microservices-should-control-the-ui/